# Indentation of one-line zsh for loops

Tags: indentation, zsh

My EMACS (26.3) thinks the line after

```
for i (`seq 1 10`) echo $i
```

should be indented.  Is this a bug?

Comment: If the indentation is incorrect, then it's a bug.  Whether the indentation is correct is not an Emacs-related question.  So either ask the question to a zsh-related group, or `M-x report-emacs-bug`, or ask a different question.

Comment: @Drew, `sh-mode`.  mode line shows zsh is recognized.  typing the line in zsh works, so i don't think anything is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sh-use-smie` is set to t the [Simple Minded Indentation Engine (SMIE)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/SMIE.html) is used for indentation. As you experience, the `sh-mode` setup for SMIE does not cover [all the alternate complex commands of zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Alternate-Forms-For-Complex-Commands) yet.

Note that those forms should not be used in new programs. I cite the [zsh doc](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Alternate-Forms-For-Complex-Commands):

> These are non-standard and are likely not to be obvious even to seasoned shell programmers; they should not be used anywhere that portability of shell code is a concern.

Nevertheless, it may be that you have to fight with such forms in legacy software.

If you set `sh-use-smie` to nil the line after the short form of the alternate form of `for` is not indented.

Disclaimer: I do not know the negative consequences of setting `sh-use-smie` to nil.

This bug already has a [long-standing bug report on bug-gnu-emacs](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-11/msg01199.html).
It is also registered in the [bug tracker](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19176). But it looks like nobody cares.

Comment: I don't see that the cited passage actually says they shouldn't be used in new programmes, or implies it?  In any case, this is just a line in my `zshrc`, so I think I'll just change it to the normal form.